# What is the best library in python or R that implements LSTM networks?

Tags: r, machine-learning, python, text-mining, lstm

After searching I have got the following link but this seems to be implemented in Lua programming language.
I have customer reviews data of TripAdvisor hotels and I am trying to do text mining over it.
I have 2 goals:-

1. sentiment analysis i.e. categorising reviews as positive or negative
2. semantic relationships between reviews if any(exploratory)

Only issue is that I am not able to find any help on Python or R on this.

Answer (score 3):

There're many implementations of RNN with the LSTM architecture on python. `Tensorflow`, `Keras` and `Theano` come to mind. If you must work in R, your best bet is the `mxnet` package, which has an implementation of the LSTM recurrent neural net with an example on NLP. This package is quite new so don't expect smooth sailing.

Answer (score 1):

For python, the keras library (built on top of theano) has an LSTM implementation: https://github.com/fchollet/keras

Here's a demo you can reference: 
http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/